# Простой эхо-сервер под Linux

Tags: linux

Здравствуйте!

Реализую сервер через именованные каналы, столкнулся с проблемой... Вот задание: Клиент читает текст из stdin и передает его серверу, сервер возвращает его клиенту. Клиент выводит на stdout ответ сервера и время, прошедшее между отправкой текста серверу и получением ответа от сервера.

Подскажите, каким образом можно сообщить клиенту об окончании записи в канал? (У меня сервер-одна программа с двумя процессами: 1-й пишет в канал, 2-й читает из него, а клиент другая.)

Comment: Если передается простая строка, то может, `'\0'` послужит меткой конца передачи?

Comment: @Alerr, не думаю, что использовать FIFO таким образом (для двустороннего обмена) это хорошая идея.

Если Вам нужна адресация через имена в файловой системе, и *обмен* данными, то почему бы не взять socket(AF_LOCAL,...)?

IMHO FIFO хороши как средство "рандеву" с последующей передачей данных в одну сторону. Конечно, ничто не мешает клиенту передать серверу имя другого FIFO, через который он будет отправлять ответ.

Comment: ))))) эхххх, это не моя прихоть, это лектор лабу написал.... Попробовал через сигнал sigusr2, убунта отрубилась... Не, нельзя 2-й канал делать... Есть какие идеи?

Comment: Закрытие файла со стороны пишущего процесса заставляет read выйти из ожидания.

Comment: @Alerr, синхронизация через сигналы... Не очень я это люблю, но для лабы можно, наверное.

А как именно Вы ubuntu отрубили? Что же такого надо сделать в лабе, чтобы ось сломалась?

Comment: Послал kill(-1, sigusr2); и все окна отрубились...

Comment: Спасибо sercxjo!!!!

Comment: @Alerr, перед экспериментами `man 2 kill` почитайте

    If pid equals -1, then sig is sent to every process for which the call‐
       ing  process  has  permission  to  send  signals,  except for process 1
       (init), but see below.

Comment: Читал ман, знаю, надеялся что сработает....)

Comment: Извините, а что, select() не работает? Или это винды?

Comment: @alexlz, а select() в данной ситуации ничего не меняет. Вот запишет клиент в fifo данные, вызовет select(), тот ему сообщит, что в fifo данные есть, клиент их же (только что им записанные) и прочтет.

Comment: @avp После общения с местными колдунами может крыша съехать.
@Alerr Что значит "окончание записи в канал"? Туда уже больше писаться не будет, или просто записана очередная порция, её надо забрать?

Comment: Если чтение и запись производить через один дескриптор, то записываемые в него данные вроде бы не должны через него возвращаться

Comment: нет, действительно возвращаются, проще использовать два fifo файла для передачи информации в двух направлениях

Answer (score 1):

[@Alerr](/users/3147/alerr), ну идея (абсолютно непродуктивная) здесь может быть очень простая. Клиент в начале своего сообщения пишет серверу свой pid, а сервер перед эхо свой.

```
cli -> c-pid text
cli pause
cli <- s-pid text
cli kill s-pid

serv <- c-pid text
serv -> s-pid text
serv kill c-pid
serv pause
```

Для пары это должно сработать.

Вы уверены, что эта мутотень Вам нужна? Может задание как-то немного по другому можно интерпретировать?

Comment: разобрался, всё проще, не надо посылать сигнал серверу чтобы он читаллл там спец фишки: 1 надо использовать то что из пустого канала ничего не читается, 2 пишет\читает из канала только один процесс...

Comment: @Alerr, что-то Вы путаете. У Вас что, сервер пишет эхо не в тот же канал, который читает?

Comment: @sercxjo, там у меня комментарии кончились. Вы пишете

    Если чтение и запись производить через один дескриптор, то записываемые в него данные вроде бы не должны через него возвращаться

к сожалению это не так. Делаете в FIFO write() и тут же (с тем же дескриптором (а может и с другим - без разницы)) read() и читаете только что записанные байты. 

Если читают несколько процессов, то может прочесть другой, тогда будете ждать на этом read(), пока кто-то в этот FIFO не запишет (или через сигнал не выйдите).

Comment: проверил, да читаются обратно и через тот же дескриптор, если сервер замешкается, то клиент прочитает сам себя

Comment: @sercxjo, там у меня комментарии кончились. 

о 2-х fifo автор уже сказал

    это не моя прихоть, это лектор лабу написал..... Не, нельзя 2-й канал делать...

некрасиво, согласен, но echo сделать можно.